# How to form a stick table based on url parameter in Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I have following url on which the client can hit.

```
/AnEndPoint?User=<user_emailid>&DeviceId=<device_id>
```

I want to rate limit user based on User+DeviceId combination.

For ex a User A with DeviceId 123 is making more than x request/sec should be added to stick table and further request is denied

I see something here https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-url_param

I have some sample config here which works on Deviceid how can expand this to also store useremail+Deviceid and block on those only.

```
frontend frontend1

    http-request set-var(txn.email) urlp(User)
    http-request set-var(txn.deviceid) urlp(DeviceId)
    http-request deny if { var(txn.deviceid),table_http_req_rate(Abuse) ge 10 }

    http-request track-sc0 var(txn.deviceid) table Abuse


backend somebackend
   stick store-request var(txn.deviceid)  table Abuse #ONLY STORING DEVICEID ,HOW TO STORE EMAIL WITH IT TOO?
backend Abuse
 stick-table type string size 100K expire 30m store http_req_rate(10s)
```

I am having problem in understanding how can i insert and increment value generated with each request's query string in stick table.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this.

```
backend Backend1
    http-request set-header  UserInfo       %[urlp(User)]%[urlp(DeviceId)]
    stick store-request hdr(UserInfo) table Abuse
    http-request track-sc0 hdr(UserInfo) table Abuse
    http-request deny if { hdr(UserInfo),table_http_req_rate(Abuse) ge 5 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting an additional header, which might have side effects such as leaking information to the external backend server, you can use `set-var-fmt`as describe [here](https://ruderich.org/simon/notes/#haproxy):

```
backend Backend1
    http-request set-var-fmt(req.user_info) %[urlp(User)]%[urlp(DeviceId)]
    stick store-request var(req.user_info) table Abuse
    http-request track-sc0 var(req.user_info) table Abuse
    http-request deny if { var(req.user_info),table_http_req_rate(Abuse) ge 5 }
```