# how to haproxy block user and device with status code 401

Tags: haproxy

I found this topic
[How to form a stick table based on url parameter in Haproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736577/how-to-form-a-stick-table-based-on-url-parameter-in-haproxy/)

i need to block user an deviceid when status code 401 only.
can someone help me?

i try this.and try to use stick table.

Answer (score 1):

it's work for me.

```
 backend xxxxxx
 http-request set-header UserInfo %[urlp(User)]%[urlp(DeviceId)]
 stick store-request hdr(UserInfo) table Abuse
 http-request track-sc0 hdr(UserInfo) table Abuse
 http-request deny if { hdr(UserInfo),table_http_err_rate(Abuse) ge 5 }

 backend Abuse
 stick-table type string size 100K expire 30m store conn_rate(1s),http_req_rate(1s),http_err_rate(10s)"
```